# Odd issue with error - Makefile:3: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: linux, driver, intel, ethernet

I was trying to install intel ethernet driver I219-V for my desktop, but when I follow the instruction and it gives me error when I do "make load" for the make file. I have been searching on the similar issue on the internet, but it seems my issue is a bit weird. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The error I got is:

```
Makefile:3: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I tried checking with cat -e -t -v  Makefile
but the result seems fine, I am not sure where I should add another tab. Please help me on this, I am pretty new to linux.
Here is the result when I do cat -e -t -v  Makefile

```
#$FreeBSD$$
$
.include <bsd.own.mk>$
$
.PATH: ${.CURDIR}$
$
KMOD=if_em$
SRCS=device_if.h bus_if.h pci_if.h$
SRCS+=$(CORE_SRC) $(COMMON_SHARED) $(LEGACY_SHARED) $(PCIE_SHARED)$
CORE_SRC=if_em.c if_lem.c e1000_osdep.c em_compat.c$
# Shared$
COMMON_SHARED=e1000_api.c e1000_phy.c e1000_nvm.c e1000_mac.c e1000_manage.c$
PCIE_SHARED=e1000_80003es2lan.c e1000_ich8lan.c e1000_82571.c$
LEGACY_SHARED=e1000_82540.c e1000_82542.c e1000_82541.c e1000_82543.c$
$
# These flags are only used when in a standalone tarball build$
CFLAGS+= -DINET -DINET6 -DEM_STANDALONE_BUILD$
$
# Uncomment this to disable Fast interrupt handling.$
#CFLAGS  += -DEM_LEGACY_IRQ$
$
# DEVICE_POLLING for a non-interrupt-driven method$
#CFLAGS  += -DDEVICE_POLLING$
$
# Uncomment this to enable the stack multiqueue routines$
# with this driver you do not get multiple tx queues,$
# but it does provide input queuing. Testing has shown$
# some stability issues so its off by default.$
# NOTE: it has been found that UDP intensive traffic$
#       actually does better with the old stack interface$
#       and so it seems better to have this off by default.$
#       however it works fine, and some workloads may benefit$
#       having it on.$
#CFLAGS  += -DEM_MULTIQUEUE$
$
clean:$
^Irm -f opt_bdg.h device_if.h bus_if.h pci_if.h setdef*$
^Irm -f *.o *.kld *.ko$
^Irm -f @ machine export_syms x86$
^Irm -f ${CLEANFILES}$
.include <bsd.kmod.mk>$
```